# How do I use python program to build chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to build a chrome extension where I can run the python program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Python. Google Chrome Extensions uses Web Technologies HTML/CSS/JS and NPAPI.

Please refer to the Getting Started Guide:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to write your python code and to upload the files,

go through the documentation [here](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/developer/dashboard?hl=en#)